# Meteor Iron Router: How to handle a redirected url with double slash

Tags: redirect, meteor, iron-router

I have made a redirection from the old website to the new one. The new website is built with Meteor and Iron Router. The redirected url is:
https://example.com//redirected-url

As you can see there is a double slash in this url.
For some reason I cannot work with the htaccess file of the old website to modify the regex.
So my last option is to handle this kind of route with Iron Router.

Do you know how to manage this kind of route with Iron Router ?

**Update:**

Here a sample of router configuration (all routes follow the same config):

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: "layout",
  loadingTemplate: "loading"
});

Router.map(function () {
  this.route("route-name", {
    path:"/",
    template:"template-name",
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe("list");
    }
});

// catch all route for unhandled routes 
this.route("notfound", {
  path:"*"
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What paths have you tried setting in the Router.map() function?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the answer with a configuration model that I used. In fact, I'm looking for a way to redirect an url with double slash to "notfound" route.

Comment: Just to be sure, using `/%2F` as the path does not match `//`?

Comment: Unfortunately, /%2F, /%, /%*, */% does not match //

Comment: I'd suggest posting the internal iron-router code which does the actual matching (find it via stepping into it with browser's debugger or just browsing the source on github).  Once you've found that we can test it directly and figure out how to force a match.

Comment: Thanks Alanning, but I don't understand what you suggest. Instead I tried something (view answer).

Comment: any suggestions or way to above this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it was the right thing to do, but it worked.

```
Template.mainTemplate.rendered = function() {
    if(
        window.location.pathname === "//url-example-1"
        || window.location.pathname === "//url-example-2"
        || window.location.pathname === "//url-etc"  
    ){  Router.go("home")  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I did almost the same as @Carl B. Suggested, but instead or use Router.go("Home") which I dont know why didnt worked for me I used location.href javascript method.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Template.Home.rendered = function(){
        if(window.location.pathname === "//"){
            location.href = "/";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but in case someone encounters same issue.

I had same problem, The fix was to figure out why the double slash was there!

And the reason was: When I sat up the redirect url, I had an extra slash at the end of the redirect url. e.g: http://www.something.com/ I changed this to http://www.something.com and then got no more problems.